# Change font color inside input or textarea

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want the following text inside the input field to be white as shown in the picture below:

[image: here the picture]

And here is the code:

---

```
<v-flex xs12 sm6 md3>
   <v-text-field color="white" label="Name" style="">
   </v-text-field>
</v-flex>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the default css

```
.theme--light.v-input:not(.v-input--is-disabled) input{
  color:#fff;
}
```